# close button css position

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a modal with a close button on the bottom. It seems like it is moving up and down depending on how long the comment section right on top. I'm trying to fix the position of it on the bottom no matter how long the comment section is. So I used *relative*, but I would appreciate it if you guys have better idea to fix this. Thanks.

View:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="modal-title title">
        <p>@ViewBag.name<span> Info</span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="info">
        <p>@Html.Label("Name: ") @ViewBag.name</p>
        <p>@Html.Label("Age: ") @ViewBag.age</p>
        <p>@Html.Label("Comment: ") @ViewBag.comment</p>
    </div>
    <div id="close">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="button" id="closeButton" value="Close" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background: white;   
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 10px 0; 
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.title {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
.title p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.title span {
    color: black;   
}
#info {    
    position: relative;     
    top: 50px;
    left: 20px;
}
#info p {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    width: 310px;
}
#close {
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just gave fixed height to the modal body so that body can be scrolled with out changing the button position

```
enter code h
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="height:200px; overflow-y:scroll;">
           <p>@Html.Label("Name: ") @ViewBag.name</p>
        <p>@Html.Label("Age: ") @ViewBag.age</p>
        <p>@Html.Label("Comment: ") @ViewBag.comment</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <input type="button" id="closeButton" value="Close" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

ere

Answer (score 0):

Just add position: fixed and sink it to the bottom if thats what you want.

```
#close {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: yeah, but then depends on the screen size, (ex: if I made it a full screen pressing F11) it goes out of the box. how can I make that button stick to the bottom of the modal regardless of the screen resolution?

Comment: i pressed f11 from the fiddle and i still see it on the bottom